# How to slideUp slowly for next element after called a jquery hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am still learning jquery. So may I know that how am I going to slideUp or animate the next element slowly after I tapped a button to hide the current element. I am using jquery .hide("slide",1000) with a button to hide current element so the style of the element will be display:none. However, the next element will move up quite fast which is not the result that i wanted.

For example,

```
Element 1
Element 2 
Element 3
```

After i removed,

```
     Element1
Element2  <---- is hiding via hide("slide",1000)
     Element3
```

What I am expecting for,

```
Element1
...       ^  moving up / sliding up slowly maybe 1-2 secs with animation.
Element3  |
```

**Added fiddle for better understanding.**

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/85jmo5s0/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

Script:

```js
$('.element').click(function(event) {
  $(this).hide("slide", {
    direction: "left"
  }, 1000);
  $(this).next().slideUp("normal");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div class="element">element1</div>
<div class="element">element2</div>
<div class="element">element3</div>
<div class="element">element4</div>
```

Don't forget to load `JQuery` and `JQueryUI`

Here's a working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/vyafL3cr/4/

Comment: Hi, is there a way to put a slideUp animation to the next element after u removed the current element. So that it will have the feels like smoother animation  when u remove and slowly slide up to join the top element.

Comment: yea, that is what i wanted. Thank you!